# Como posiciono una imagen a la izquierda de mi login?

Tags: html, css, html5, imagen, diseño

Buenos dias Chicos tengo una consulta de vida o muerte, resulta que estoy tratando de posicionar una imagen de Klee (Genshin Impact) a la izquierda de mi Login, resulta que al momento de intentarlo, esta se coloca abajo a la iquierda del login pero no al lado he buscado como hacerlo y de momento no me ha dado resultado
el html es el siguiente:

[image: html de la imagen]

El CSS es el siguiente:

[image: css de la imagen]

como resultado me da:
[image: imagen de mi login con imagen de klee]

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega un [mcve]

Comment: ahi edité puse imagen, entre otras cosas uwu

Comment: Me refiero a que por favor proveas el HTML y CSS mínimo necesario para poder reproducir el problema que se te presenta

Comment: El  **float:left** debe tenerlo el formulario todos los elementos que vayan despues flotarán con el a menos que se establezca la propiedad **clear**.

Comment: Con la información que diste el ejemplo no se puede replicar, pasa la parte de tu html y de css de tu vista completa

Comment: Como te han indicado, pulsa en [edit] y agrega un [repro], _como texto, con formato_. [Las imágenes no se pueden ejecutar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/) :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es usar un layout flexbox. Este modelo de CSS distribuye bloques de contenido en horizontal o vertical, en este caso te interesa horizontal (rows, su valor por defecto). Los bloques pueden justificarse o alinearse con las propiedades de flex para contenedores o items contenidos. Con este esquema que te doy la imagen queda a la izuierda y en el lado derecho se puede poner el formulario.

```
.contenedor{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
 }
 
 .contenedor div{
 margin: 20x;
 flex:1;
 background:aliceblue;
 }
```

Y para el html

```
<div class="contenedor">
<div><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"></div>
<div> cuadro para el formulario</div>
</div>
```

Si sigues este camino podrás personalizar la solución

Answer (score -1):

existen varias opciones:

opcion #1:

```
.card-del-login{
    position:relative;
}
img{
   postion: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}
```

opcion #2:

```
.card-del-login>.contenedor-de-la-imagen{
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: flex-start; //puede ser flex-end dependiendo del lado que al que quieras mover la imagen
}
img{
    flex-grow:1;
    max-width: 100px; // si la imagen es HD abarcará demasiado espacio, por eso es mejor limitar a 100px o algo similar
}
```

yo recomiendo la opcion 1, también puedes darle un z-index: 0; para que la imagen quede detrás de los elementos del card

#EDIT:

en el codigo anterior la imagen deberia colocarse (creo) que sobre el boton login, si quieres que la imagen esté en alguna esquina de la pantalla entonces hay que hacer algunos cambios

```
.clase-de-imagen-estatica{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    max-width:100px;
}
```